# Is this function bounded? (Order of explosion of a function)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

I have the following function: $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f(x)=\int_x^1 \frac{(y-x)^{-\alpha}}{y}dy, \quad x\in [0,1],$$
where $\alpha\in (0,1/2)$ is some fixed parameter.

To me it seems this function is continuous on $(0,1]$ but not at $0$. It diverges. I would like to know the order of such explosion. My guess is:

$$f(x) = x^{-\alpha} g(x),$$
where
$$g(x) = x^{\alpha}\int_x^1 \frac{(y-x)^{-\alpha}}{y}dy.$$

If $g$ is bounded then I will have the order of explosion. The question is:

Is $g$ bounded? If not, how could I find out the order of explosion of $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $0 < x < y$ you can expand the integrand as $\frac{1}{y^{1+\alpha}} \frac{1}{(1 - x/y)^\alpha} = \frac{1}{y^{1+\alpha}} (1 - \alpha x/y +O(x^2/y^2).$ So it appears to be $f(x) \sim x^{-\alpha}$.

Comment: @RRL: I agree with the result, and actually I tried the same thing, but I think that it does not work. The expansion $(1-\frac xy)^{-\alpha}=1+\alpha \frac xy + O(x^2/y^2)$ makes sense for $\left| \frac xy\right| \ll 1$ and loses sense as $y\to x$. (Hope it is clear what I mean). In our integral, $y$ is allowed to come arbitrarily close to $x$. So we cannot use it in the integral as is, even if it gives a correct result.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Thanks. You are correct. The binomial series for $(1+z)^\alpha$ with $\alpha < 0$ converges for $-1 < z \leqslant 1$. So $z \sim -1$ is definitely a problem.

Comment: @RRL: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=xt.$ Then

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{a}}\int_1^{1/x}\frac{1}{(t-1)^at}\,dt.$$

Thus $f(x) \sim C/x^a,$ where

$$C = \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{(t-1)^at}\,dt.$$